# Create summary table with averages of column subsets

Tags: r

I am very new to this so be please nice!

My dataset has 3 columns - Col A (chr, 'X' and 'Y'), Col B (chr, 'red', 'blue' 'yellow'), Col C (numeric).

```
Col_A <- c('X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X')
Col_B <- c('red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'red')
Col_C <- c(12, 22, 13, 14, 25, 17, 11, 10)

dataset <- as.data.frame(cbind(Col_A, Col_B, Col_C))
```

How can I create a summary table in R that's like

```
tbl_summary(dataset, by = 'Col_A')
```

[image: output shown here]

but gives the mean values of Col C for every subgroup in Col B?
[image]

Right now the code gives me counts for Col B and then the mean value of Col C for 'X' and 'Y'.

Does any of that even make sense?!

Comment: Please add the sample data using `dput` to recreate the problem.

Comment: So you want to split it in 6 groups? X, Y * red, blue, yellow? Or just the 3 groups from Col B?

Comment: Yes exactly, 6 groups with the mean of col C for each group

Comment: Please include a table showing your expected output, this allows potential solutions to be tested and verified and avoids ambiguity.

Comment: Perhaps including a sketch of your expected output would be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
Updated with base R and dplyr options.

```r
# simpler way to create a data.frame and preserve variable types.

Col_A <- c('X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X')
Col_B <- c('red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'red')
Col_C <- c(12, 22, 13, 14, 25, 17, 11, 10)

dataset <- data.frame(Col_A, Col_B, Col_C)

#Using base R `aggregate`
aggregate(Col_C ~ Col_A + Col_B, data = dataset, mean)

# with `dplyr`
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dataset <- 
dataset %>% 
  group_by(Col_A, Col_B) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Col_C, na.rm = TRUE))

dataset

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   Col_A [2]
#>   Col_A Col_B   mean
#>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 X     blue    13  
#> 2 X     red     13  
#> 3 X     yellow  22  
#> 4 Y     blue    12.5
#> 5 Y     yellow  25

# and as a `gt` table
library(gt)
gt(dataset)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Peter, almost! I'd like to find the mean of e.g. every Y - Blue all together

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really sure I fully understand, perhaps you could include the expected output in the question I can work it out. there are two Y-blue cases with Col_C values of 11 and 14, hence a mean of 12.5. This seems to reflect the comment in the question in response to @ Wietse de Vries

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just re-read and tried with my actual dataset and it's perfect, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the data.table structure and it's by parameter

```
library(data.table)
dataset <- data.table(Col_A, Col_B, Col_C)
dataset[, mean(Col_C), keyby=Col_B]
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this. I can get that far but I also need to split that output into 'Y' and 'X'. I know I can just split the dataset in two and compute the output twice, but I was looking for a way to output it all at once :)